# Unexpected output for numpy.arange with step size of 0.005

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am creating a numpy array between two limits with a step size of 0.005 using numpy.arange. Normally I would expect the output to go up to but not include the stop point. For example, I am using the following:

```
np.arange(2.23, 2.24, 0.005)
```

From which I would expect:

```
array([ 2.23 ,  2.235])
```

However, what I am getting is:

```
array([ 2.23 ,  2.235,  2.24 ])
```

Now this is ultimately the array that I actually want since I was going to add 0.005 to my stop point but I am unclear as to why this is happening. When I use larger numbers and step sizes it behaves as normal. Is this a functionality that I was unaware of?

Comment: The docs state the following: *stop : number
End of interval. The interval does not include this value, except in some cases where step is not an integer and floating point round-off affects the length of out.*, so in your case it's being included because you're using a float as step value and because the rounding would affect the length of the returned array, see the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: Completely missed that in the docs. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linspace` might be better suited to your needs

```
In [401]: np.linspace(2.23, 2.24,3)
Out[401]: array([ 2.23 ,  2.235,  2.24 ])
```

You specify the number of steps, rather than the interval.  It has additional parameters to control details like the inclusion, or not, of the end point.

```
In [415]: np.linspace(2.23, 2.24,2,endpoint=False)
Out[415]: array([ 2.23 ,  2.235])
```